# C2664: "BOOL PlaySoundA (LPCSTR,HMODULE,DWORD)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из unsigned char в LPCSTR

Tags: c++, компиляция

Есть массив, который я пытаюсь проиграть через PlaySoundA

(https://pastebin.com/dqCvsmmB)

Пытаюсь проиграть следующим образом:

```
PlaySoundA(hitsound_wav, NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_MEMORY);
```

Но компилятор выдаёт ошибку:

> error C2664: "BOOL PlaySoundA(LPCSTR,HMODULE,DWORD)": невозможно
>   преобразовать аргумент 1 из "unsigned char [11752]" в "LPCSTR."

Кто может подсказать, как это исправить?

Пробовал писать 
`PlaySoundA((LPCSTR)hitsound_wav, NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_MEMORY)`
, но выдавало ошибку LINK2001.

Comment: Все правильно сделали, это была уже другая ошибка.

Comment: Не можете подсказать, в чём может быть проблема ?

Comment: Без текста ошибки - не могу. Хотя погодите, сейчас достану свой хрустальный шар... вот он. Может надо добавить `Winmm.lib` в список библиотек?

Comment: Добавлял в компоновщик.